# Как вывести все значения массива?

Tags: php

Как вывести все значения `["amount"]=> int(1)` а именно значение 1 из всего массива?

Весь массив

```
array(10) { [0]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [1]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [2]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [3]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [4]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [5]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [6]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [7]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [8]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [9]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> int(1) ["currency"]=> int(643) } }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $arr = json_decode($httpResponse, true);
    $values = [];
    foreach($arr['data'] as $data){
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            if($key == 'sum'){
                //$balance = $value['amount'];
                $values[] = $value;
                echo "<br/>Пополнил " .$values[0]["amount"]. " руб.<br>";
            }
        }
    }
```